# How to implement Twilio Conference HangUpOnStar in C#

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-twiml, conference

What would the equivalent of this Twilio TwiML be in C#? I'm most interested in implementing the hangupOnStar in C# and passing the call to another URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
<Dial hangupOnStar="true">
    <Conference>ConferenceOne</Conference>
</Dial>
<Gather action="http://example.ngrok.io/Conference/Join" numDigits="1">
    <Say>To mute all participants, press one</Say>
    <Say>To leave the conference, press two</Say>
</Gather>
</Response>
```

Comment: It will be the same. You just need to write C# code using TwiML C# library to generate the TwiML you want.

Answer (score 1):

"hanguponstar" has to be added to "Dial" example:

> var dial = new Dial(hangupOnStar: true);

```
// POST: Conference/Connect
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Connect(string digits)
    {
        var isMuted = digits.Equals("1"); // Listener
        var canControlConferenceOnEnter = digits.Equals("3"); // Moderator

        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Say("You have joined the conference");

        var dial = new Dial(hangupOnStar: true);
        dial.Conference("ConferenceRoom",
            waitUrl: new Uri("http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.rock"),                
            muted: isMuted,
            startConferenceOnEnter: canControlConferenceOnEnter,
            endConferenceOnExit: canControlConferenceOnEnter);
            response.Append(dial);
        response.Gather();

        return TwiML(response);

    }
```